# AChartEngine crashes after adding points and panning

Tags: java, android, charts, nullpointerexception, achartengine

I'm building an Android app with [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine) and am getting weird errors.

**After I add new points to my already established chart and touch/pan the graph, I get a `NullPointerException`** in `LineChart(XYChart).getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(Point)`, where `GraphicalView`'s variables `oldX` and `oldY` are discovered to be null. These variables are set in `GraphicalView.onTouchEvent()`, but that is apparently not being called.

Is there a way to manually trigger `onTouchEvent()` when initializing my graph, or is there a workaround to this error?

Here is my chart set up code:

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
        double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
        if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(viewer.this,
                    "No chart element was clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    viewer.this,
                    "Chart element clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is how I add new points:

```
protected class NewPoints extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Double... values) {
        mCurrentSeries.add(values[0], values[1]); // x, y

        if (mChartView != null) {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My testing code:

```
for(double i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new NewPoints().execute(i, Math.log(i));
}
```

Here is the LogCat output:

```
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(XYChart.java:840)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint(GraphicalView.java:135)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at com.maximz.viewer$1.onClick(viewer.java:185)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-20 18:46:12.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13800):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update 1:**

I've recompiled with the AChartEngine source code and debugging shows that the error takes place in this method:

```
public SeriesSelection getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(final Point screenPoint) {
    if (clickableAreas != null)
      for (int seriesIndex = clickableAreas.size() - 1; seriesIndex >= 0; seriesIndex--) {
        // series 0 is drawn first. Then series 1 is drawn on top, and series 2
        // on top of that.
        // we want to know what the user clicked on, so traverse them in the
        // order they appear on the screen.
        int pointIndex = 0;
        if (clickableAreas.get(seriesIndex) != null) {
          RectF rectangle;
          for (ClickableArea area : clickableAreas.get(seriesIndex)) {
            rectangle = area.getRect(); // EXCEPTION HERE: area is null
            if (rectangle != null && rectangle.contains(screenPoint.getX(), screenPoint.getY())) {
              return new SeriesSelection(seriesIndex, pointIndex, area.getX(), area.getY());
            }
            pointIndex++;
          }
        }
      }
    return super.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(screenPoint);
  }
```

The exception is thrown at the `rectangle = area.getRect();` line, where `area` is null since **`clickableAreas.get(0)` somehow returns a collection of null clickableAreas**.

I'm going to try to patch this with a check to see if the clickableArea is null, but this begs the question: **am I adding points correctly?**

Comment: Could you post your Logcat that's pointing the exception remaining?

Comment: Are you get the answer or not?

Comment: @Venkatesh: I've edited the question and added the relevant LogCat output.

Answer (score 1):

As per the stacktrace, the exception occurs in the second line in the following code of XYChart.java (if my source code has matching line numbers):

```
for (ClickableArea area : clickableAreas.get(seriesIndex)) {
    rectangle = area.getRect();  // <--- Exception here!
    if (rectangle != null && rectangle.contains(screenPoint.getX(), screenPoint.getY())) {
        return new SeriesSelection(seriesIndex, pointIndex, area.getX(), area.getY());
    }
    pointIndex++;
}
```

I can't see how that can happen.

**Can you compile your code with AChartEngine's source and debug?**

Further `oldX` & `oldY` are both declared as primitive `float`s in GraphicalView.java. How can they be `null` if they are primitives?

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I've updated the question with the results of the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer Exception might be Caused by your AchartEngine jar files sometimes goes to out of usage while no longer used it. So you should check the jar files on your build path by right click on your project . From that choose the options

```
    Order and Export->choose your jar files->click up and down button.
```

It could be used to turning on your jar files used in your project.

Comment: Please check it. While it's not you are looking for then tell me i will helps you further.

Comment: AChartEngine is enabled under `Order and Export`. Are you saying I should also move it to the top of the list? I thought order didn't matter for dependencies.